# A subgroup of sharply $4$-transitive group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a sharply $4$-transitive group on a set $S=\{1,2,3,4,\ldots\}$: given subsets $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ and $\{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\}$ of $S$, there is unique $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot x_i=y_i$.

Let $t=(1,2)(3)(4)\cdots$ be a permutation in $G$ and consider
$$
H=\{ g\in G\,\,:\,\, g \mbox{ fixes } 1 \mbox{ and } g \mbox{ commutes with } t\}.
$$
Since $t^2$ fixes at least four points, so it should be identity.

Next, $t$ has only $2$ or $3$ fixed points ($\Leftarrow$ sharp $4$-transitivity), and $H$ permutes them.

Further, $H$ acts faithfully on the fixed points of $t$ (**why?**)

Therefore $|H|\le 6$ (**why?**)

---

**Ref:** Permutation Groups by Peter Cameron, Theorem $1.11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Let $F(t)$ denote the set of points fixed by $t$. An element $h$ of $H$  that fixed each point of $F(t)$ would also fix $1$ and $2$, and so $h$ would fix each of the points $1,2,3,4$. But then $h$ would be equal to the identity by sharp $4$-transitivity. So $h=1$, which proves that $H$ acts faithfully on the fixed points of $t$.

Question 2: Now $H$ is acting faithfully on a set of two or three points, and hence $|H| \le 3! = 6$.

Comment: can you please explain "..an element h of H that fixed all of that fixed all of the fixed points of t would fix each .. "?

Comment: Sorry, I was stuttering. The words "that fixed all of" were repeated - fixed now.